# Arellano and Bond (1991) GMM estimation in R by using plm package

Tags: r, panel-data, generalized-method-of-moments

I am a last-year student at university, currently working on my Bachelor's (so still learning R), and I really hope that you would suggest a potential solution (even if to use Python).

So, the main model for my bachelor is as follows:
[Main model for the Thesis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVUCP.png)

I need to estimate this model by using the GMM (preferably Arellano and Bond (1991)). I have been searching for the solution for almost 2 months, yet still not succeeded.

The data set could be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15NBcZ7TBfoJ7TnM3BYgtt5JW3T3CmqGJ/view?usp=sharing

My code is the following:

```
PDataA2 <- pdata.frame(DataA2, index = c("ID","Year"))

z1 <- pgmm(domega ~ lag(domega, 1) + ddebt + ff1 + ff1:ddebt + Age + ta + dsales | lag(domega, 2),
           data = PDataA2, effect = "twoways", model = "twosteps", index = c("ID", "Year"), transformation = "ld")

summary(z1, robust = TRUE)
```

*domega* is TFP growth, *ddebt* - debt growth, *ta* - log of total assets, *dsales* - sales growth.

ff1, ff2, ff3, ff4, ff5 stands for financial frictions in the model.

After I have created all the needed variables, I am trying to estimate coefficients by using *pgmm* function in *plm* package. And receive 2 errors:

In case I use `transformation = "d"`, errors are as follows:
[1 type of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtQIk.png)

In case I use `transformation = "ld"`, errors are as follows:
[2 type of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPyiO.png)

In case I delete lag from the model and put it after "|" sign I get:
[3 type of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUtxP.png)

I would really appreciate any comments and suggestions provided because I do not know how to get away from this dead end. Thank you in advance!)

Please ask for the data and any explanation, since I am really desperate to find the solution.

UPD: here is a correlation matrix:

```
                  domegaACF_A        ddebt          ff1          Age          ta       dsales lag1_domegaACF_A lag2_domegaACF_A
domegaACF_A       1.000000000 -0.014777102 -0.002600866 -0.019160423  0.02456158  0.256801279     -0.379350157     -0.027687422
ddebt            -0.014777102  1.000000000  0.128264730  0.004706522  0.03878795  0.057488971      0.018800962     -0.003222902
ff1              -0.002600866  0.128264730  1.000000000 -0.048072279 -0.02868682  0.008979745     -0.002808377      0.008062733
Age              -0.019160423  0.004706522 -0.048072279  1.000000000  0.27884112 -0.021440539     -0.051829392     -0.048162046
ta                0.024561579  0.038787947 -0.028686815  0.278841116  1.00000000  0.078247618      0.015304990      0.015539599
dsales            0.256801279  0.057488971  0.008979745 -0.021440539  0.07824762  1.000000000     -0.049518811     -0.004134281
lag1_domegaACF_A -0.379350157  0.018800962 -0.002808377 -0.051829392  0.01530499 -0.049518811      1.000000000     -0.358671174
lag2_domegaACF_A -0.027687422 -0.003222902  0.008062733 -0.048162046  0.01553960 -0.004134281     -0.358671174      1.000000000
```

Comment: with the large amount of data pre-processing involving various packages before you come to the command you asked about, I feel like no one will want to dive into your queston/code.

Comment: @Helix123, Thank you for the advice! Updated.

Comment: Any other suggestions? or any advice?